# SQL DML - unable to use the after function in modify

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, database-administration, dml

I need to update around 1000 xml records with a new xml node, the xml's are stored in a sql table column, with xml datatype, So I've been trying to utilize the modify function documented [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/insert-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver15) (specifically example A.4)

However, When I run this against my staging environment (SqlServer 2016 SP2-CU13) I receive the following error message:

> Msg 2395, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
> XQuery [production.dbo.organisations.Configuration.modify()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:AFTER()'

The code is rudimentary, I'm just stumped by the error message. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated

Code:

```
update [production].[dbo].[organisations] Set configuration.modify('INSERT <LegalEntityName>TEST</LegalEntityName> AFTER (/OrganisationMetaData/ExamPrepAssessModeFromAddress)[1]') where ID = 1
```

Comment: Curious what happens if you try it lowercase? `insert ... after ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember XML is always case-sensitive, eg:

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists organisations 
go
create table organisations(id int, configuration xml)
insert into organisations(id, configuration) values (1,'<OrganisationMetaData><ExamPrepAssessModeFromAddress></ExamPrepAssessModeFromAddress></OrganisationMetaData>')

update organisations Set configuration.modify('insert <LegalEntityName>TEST</LegalEntityName> after (/OrganisationMetaData/ExamPrepAssessModeFromAddress)[1]') where ID = 1
```